# Inherit a class from a gem and add local methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use a gem to manage certain attributes of a gmail api integration, and I'm pretty happy with the way it works.

I want to add some local methods to act on the Gmail::Message class that is used in that gem.

i.e. I want to do something like this.

```
models/GmailMessage.rb
  class GmailMessage < Gmail::Message

    def initialize(gmail)
      #create a Gmail::Message instance as a GmailMessage instance 
      self = gmail
    end

    def something_clever
      #do something clever utilising the Gmail::Message methods
    end
  end
```

I don't want to persist it. But obviously I can't define self in that way.

To clarify, I want to take an instance of Gmail::Message and create a GmailMessage instance which is a straight copy of that other message.

I can then run methods like @gmail.subject and @gmail.html, but also run @gmail.something_clever... and save local attributes if necessary.

Am I completely crazy?

Comment: Spelling of `initialize` is wrong, and you cannot assign value to `self` - use instance variable - like `@gmail`.

Comment: If I define @gmail, I'll just define an attribute gmail that is the message. 
I want the message to 'be' the same thing or at least an exact copy with all the same methods and attributes (up until I add some more stuff that won't be accessible to the Gmail::Message class).

Comment: If it helps, the instance itself appears to be a simple json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use concept of `mixin`, wherein you include a `Module` in another class to enhance it with additional functions.

Here is how to do it. To create a complete working example, I have created  modules that resemble what you may have in your code base.

```
# Assumed to be present in 3rd party gem, dummy implementation used for demonstration
module Gmail
    class Message
        def initialize
            @some_var = "there"
        end
        def subject
            "Hi"
        end
    end
end

# Your code
module GmailMessage
    # You can code this method assuming as if it is an instance method
    # of Gmail::Message. Once we include this module in that class, it
    # will be able to call instance methods and access instance variables.
    def something_clever
        puts "Subject is #{subject} and @some_var = #{@some_var}"
    end
end

# Enhance 3rd party class with your code by including your module
Gmail::Message.include(GmailMessage)

# Below gmail object will actually be obtained by reading the user inbox
# Lets create it explicitly for demonstration purposes.
gmail = Gmail::Message.new

# Method can access methods and instance variables of gmail object
p gmail.something_clever  
#=> Subject is Hi and @some_var = there

# You can call the methods of original class as well on same object
p gmail.subject
#=> "Hi"
```

Comment: I like this a lot. 
Benefit is that it's easier to apply universally.
Downside is that I once I have an instance I don't know whether it has the extra methods included or not. (could do a responds_to? I suppose). 
With the class inheritance idea, the aim was to explicitly use it for a specific purpose.

Comment: Sicne we are doing `include` for class `Gmail::Message`, all instances will have the methods from `GmailMessage` module - irrespective of whether instance was created before calling `include` or after.

Answer (score 1):

Following should work:

```
class GmailMessage < Gmail::Message

  def initialize(extra)
    super
    # some additional stuff
    @extra = extra
  end

  def something_clever
    #do something clever utilising the Gmail::Message methods
  end

end

GmailMessage.new # => will call first the initializer of Gmail::Message class..
```

Comment: This will work only if one is creating instance of `GmailMessage` directly - how can you convert an instance of `Gmail::Message` to `GmailMessage` which is what OP is asking.

Comment: Scratch this ----> Perfect.. As it happens, I don't need 'extra' as I won't be adding extra things at the initialization step, just later on once I've done some processing...
Knew it would be something simple... This is rails after all...

Comment: @KeiranBetteley Are you sure this is what you want?  I thought you had an instance of `Gmail::Message` and you wanted it to become `GmailMessage` object.  That is not possible.

Comment: You're right. (My test was rubbish). This isn't creating the GmailMessage object with the Gmail::Message object's properties.
Was hoping it was this easy....

Comment: @WandMaker you are right. My example only shows how you can "use" the parent class methods and stuff through normal inheritance. But the instance itself will not be converted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you can't just have a simple wrapper class...

```
class GmailMessage

  def initialize(message)
    @message = message
  end

  def something_clever
    # do something clever here
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)  
    if @message.class.instance_methods.include?(m)
      @message.send(m, *args, &block)
    else
      super
    end  
  end 
end
```

Then you can do...

```
  @my_message = GmailMessage.new(@original_message)
```

@my_message will correctly respond to all the methods that were supported with @original_message and you can add your own methods to the class.

EDIT  - changed thanks to @jeeper's observations in the comments

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `subject' for #<GmailMessage:0x007fcc336e4270>.

Comment: I get the correct response on @my_message.message.subject

Comment: That's unusual.  I just copied-and-pasted my code into a test app and it works fine.  did you do the `message_missing` method exactly as described?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. I'm on rails 3.2.18 and ruby 2.1. Let me check again.... Checked. I get a GmailMessage object with @message=<whateevr the original>. 
If I add an attr_accessor for :message I can get the response on @my_message.message. Otherwise I just get undefined method error

Comment: None of the code is rails dependent.  I wrote it on Ruby 1.9.3 and I know `respond_do?` returns false for protected methods under Ruby 2+ but this isn't a protected method.

Comment: Can you try a different class?  `my_object = GmailMessage.new("Hello")` then try `p my_object.upcase` ... does that print "HELLO" ?

Comment: The original `Gmail::Message`class also contains a similar `method_missing` method-forwarding-hack. So the `respond_to` check will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon what the other posters have said, you can use built-in class [SimpleDelegator](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) in ruby to wrap an existing message:

```
require 'delegate'

class MyMessage < SimpleDelegator
  def my_clever_method
    some_method_on_the_original_message + "woohoo"
  end
end

class OriginalMessage
  def some_method_on_the_original_message
    "hey"
  end

  def another_original_method
    "zoink"
  end
end

original = OriginalMessage.new
wrapper = MyMessage.new(original)

puts wrapper.my_clever_method
# => "heywoohoo"

puts wrapper.another_original_method
# => "zoink"
```

As you can see, the wrapper automatically forwards method calls to the wrapped object.

Comment: I've no idea why, but this doesn't work for me.

a.subject
NoMethodError: undefined method `subject' for #<GmailMessage:

Comment: Are you sure that the original class `Gmail::Message` has a `subject` method? If https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail/blob/master/lib/gmail/message.rb is the class you're using, it seems it doesn't. Maybe you need to call `wrapper.message.subject`?

Comment: Okay I see now that `Gmail::Message` uses `method_missing` to forward unknown method calls to it's `message` attribute. We can now see that this is a bad idea, since it makes the public API impossible to introspect.

Answer (score -1):

It's not the prettiest, but it works...

```
class GmailMessage < Gmail::Message

  def initialize(message)
    message.instance_variables.each do |variable|
      self.instance_variable_set(
        variable, 
        message.instance_variable_get(variable)
        )
    end
  end

  def something_clever
    # do something clever here
  end

end
```

Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: Why not? It's basically the only thing that actually works that I can work out...

Comment: If the original object mutates, you're new object won't see those changes. There are other more comprehensible ways of doing this.

Comment: Ok. I'm not worried about that though. In fact, I might want one or other object to mutate. 
I'd love a cleaner way of doing what I've done above... 
But none of the answers so far actually do it...

i.e. Take an object, create a new object under a new class which absorbs all of the methods from the class and any 'data' (instance variables) and allow me to run new methods on it without messing with the original class or object.

Comment: That's b/c the original object is written unwisely.

Comment: The original object isn't written unwisely, it's from a gem and is just designed to do something pretty standard. Ah, just seen your message above